# FIlter the text content and try to convert filtered content into JSON

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, node-red

I'm having an input in the form of a string variable msg.payload as given below.

```
Hi Team,
Below are the details of for the given source platform.
name=abc
status=Active
company=Discovery
FromDate=6/05/2020
ToDate=20/05/2020
Please do the needful ASAP
Thanks & Regards,
xyz
```

I want to take only the

```
name=abc
status=Active
company=Discovery
FromDate=6/05/2020
ToDate=20/05/2020
```

ignore the rest and then convert it into JSON using JavaScript like

```
{"name":"abc", "status":"Active","company":"ABCD" ,"FromDate":"6/05/2020","ToDate":"20/05/2020"}
```

How can I accomplish it? All the data in the input will be of the form key=value.

Answer (score 1):

You can take advantage of several built-in JavaScript string and array functions.

Convert input to an array of lines with [String.prototype.split()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split):

```
const lines = input.split('\n');
```

Filter out lines that don't contain an equals sign with [Array.prototype.filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter):

```
const kvPairs = lines.filter(line => line.includes('='));
```

Use [Array.prototype.forEach()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) and [String.prototype.split()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) to load the object with key-value properties:

```js
let object = {};
kvPairs.forEach(line => {
  [key, val] = line.split('=');
  object[key] = val;
});
```

Putting it all together:

```js
const input = 'Hi Team,\nBelow are the details of for the given source platform.\nname=abc\nstatus=Active\ncompany=Discovery\nFromDate=6/05/2020\nToDate=20/05/2020\nPlease do the needful ASAP\nThanks & Regards,\nxyz';

const lines = input.split('\n');

const kvPairs = lines.filter(line => line.includes('='));

let object = {};
kvPairs.forEach(line => {
  [key, val] = line.split('=');
  object[key] = val;
});

console.log('object:', object);
```